# Rename file on remote server on Python

Tags: python, sftp

I am using pysftp to access files on server using python.

```
conn = sftp.Connection(host = 'host', username = 'user', password = 'password')
remotepath = '/tmp/random/NAME_LATEST.zip'
localpath = '/home/tmp/Desktop/NAME.zip'
conn.put(localpath,remotepath)
conn.close()
```

What I want to do is, before putting the file NAME_LATEST, I want to rename the file already present with the name 'NAME_LATEST' to 'NAME+' and then put the new file as NAME_LATEST. What is a way to rename the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`conn.rename(remote_src, remote_dest)`](http://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html?highlight=rename#pysftp.Connection.rename): rename a file or directory on the remote host.

Answer (score 1):

For pysftp 0.2.8, rename documentation is available at [API page](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html). There is nothing in [cookbook](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/cookbook.html) for `rename`.